# SetImageview resource from image on cache downloaded by UIL lib

Tags: java, android, universal-image-loader

Actually I am using UIL for downloading image from my url. I used below code to download. but not I m not able to get how to display image downloaded in my Mainactivity. One thing I noted is it downloading image in cache, so I  got path of that file as /storage/android/data/test/cache/1235456. Now can u guide how can I  set this path to  image source so that I can be loaded during app startup. Or there is other better way to put these images in imageview. I read code of UIL and their sample application, bit confused.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView ivUIL = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
    String url = "myurl";
    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url,ivUIL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panache you can try to this it can help me..

```
 ImageView   ivUIL = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivUIL);

 String url = "http://innovativedevicesapps.me/Images/big banner.jpg";


 ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();
    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(GlobleArray.array.get(position).getStrUrl(), ivUIL);
```

**OR**

```
  ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url , ivUIL);
```

Comment: why you not use Picassso lib..??

Comment: Thanks a lot,  internet connection was creating issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use below classes to load images using UIL

**AnimateFirstDisplayListener.java**

```
public class AnimateFirstDisplayListener extends SimpleImageLoadingListener {

    public static final List<String> displayedImages = Collections
            .synchronizedList(new LinkedList<String>());

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        if (loadedImage != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            boolean firstDisplay = !displayedImages.contains(imageUri);
            if (firstDisplay) {
                FadeInBitmapDisplayer.animate(imageView, 500);
                displayedImages.add(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**DisplayImageOption.java**

```
public class DisplayImageOption {

    public static DisplayImageOptions getDisplayImage() {

        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().showImageOnLoading(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).showImageOnFail(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true).build();

        // .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(0))

        return options;

    }
}
```

**UILApplication.java**

```
public class UILApplication extends Application {

    public UILApplication() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
    }

    public static void initImageLoader(Context context) {
        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2).denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new Md5FileNameGenerator()).diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO).writeDebugLogs().build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }

}
```

> And finally use below code to load image

```
/*To Apply in Code*/
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("Your_Url_of_Image"
    , imageView
    , DisplayImageOption.getDisplayImage(),
    new AnimateFirstDisplayListener());
```

> Don't forget to write application name in AndroidManifest file

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.UILApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```